# method for calculating portfolio volatility

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I am trying to figure out the method for calculating the portfolio volatility using matrices.  I have read online the following definition for calculating the portfolio volatility using matrix algebra

The variance of a portfolio of correlated assets can be written as WTvW, where W is a column vector (ie a matrix with a single column) containing the weights of different assets in the portfolio.  V is the covariance matrix, and WT is the transpose of the matrix W.

I have tried to calculate this on a spreadsheet, but am not sure if i have done it correctly.  More specifically, im not sure if i am multiplying the vectors with the covariance matrix correctly.

Can someone please confirm my calculation
I have used commas below to separate the different values in the vector and matrix

assuming my weights vector is 0.89, 0.11
my covariance matrix is a 2x2 matrix = 1       ,    0.674571
                                       0.674571,    1

to calculate the result i first multiply my weights vector with the covariance matrix

i.e      0.89*1 + 0.11*0.674571
and      0.89*0.674571 + 0.11*1

which gives the following vector A    0.964202851
                                      0.710368523

I then multiply vector A with the weights vector, i.e

0.964202851    *   0.89
0.710368523        0.11     = 0.964202851*0.89+0.710368523 *0.11  = 0.936281075

Is this correct, or do i have an error in my calculation

Answer (score 2):

Your calculation is correct. By the way, there are free software packages available that make it easier to do these kinds of calculations. For example, using [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), you simply type

```
V=[1, .674571; .674571, 1]
W=[.89;.11]
W'*V*W
```

and it will give you the answer:

```
ans =  0.93628
```

Answer (score 0):

Let $R \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $w \in \mathbb{R}^d$ denote the asset returns and portfolio allocation, respectively. Assuming that $w$ is deterministic, then the portfolio return is given by $r_p = R^\prime w$, such that
\begin{equation}
Var(r_p) = Var(R^\prime w) =  w^\prime Var(R)w =  w^\prime \Sigma w
\end{equation}
where $\Sigma = Var(R)$ is the covariance matrix of asset returns.

You can calculate the same without matrix notation, which is less tractable, nonetheless:
\begin{equation}
r_p = \sum_{i=1}^d w_i \times R_i
\end{equation}
such that
\begin{equation}
Var(r_p) = Var(\sum_{i=1}^d w_i \times R_i) = \sum_{i=1}^d w_i^2 Var(r_i) + \sum_{i \neq j}^d w_i w_j Cov(r_i,r_j)
\end{equation}